# Largura de impressão em impressora térmica, WPF e C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Olá, estou fazendo um programa para imprimir lista de atividades em impressoras térmicas, nele eu coloco essas informações dentro de uma tabela (criada em código apenas para impressão, de largura total por volta de 250, e tamanho de fonte como 12), e a tabela dentro de um FlowDocument e então imprimo com o método `PrintDocument` de um `PrintDialog`, o problema é que dependendo da impressora o conteúdo está sendo impresso muito grande, sendo que gostaria que ficasse com tamanho igual em qualquer impressora térmica, cuja largura da folha segue o padrão de 80mm. Eu já tentei até transformar a tabela em uma imagem e tentar pegar a largura indicada em `PrintDialog.PrintableAreaWidth` e imprimir como imagem com essa largura, mas não obtive sucesso...

Resumindo: Preciso obter uma forma de que o tamanho da fonte e largura da impressão sejam iguais independente da impressora pensando em papeis de 80mm.

Comment: Olá Rune. Sua pergunta é boa - deixo aqui apenas a dica de que se você editá-la para incluir o código que já tentou usar como exemplo, você terá mais chances de obter uma boa resposta, além de conseguir uma resposta mais rápido.

Answer (score 1):

A solução provável será adotar o padrão `ESC/POS` acreditos que todas impressoras térmicas adotam este padrão.

Por experiência, EPSON, ELGIN, BEMATECH, já testei, obviamente alguns comandos deste padrão pode se aplicar a um modelo e outro não, por exemplo, corte de papel só tem efeito em impressora com guilhotina.

Aqui tem um [Exemplo de utilização](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704989/Print-Direct-To-Windows-Printer-EPOS-Receipt)

Documentação: [Aqui](http://content.epson.de/fileadmin/content/files/RSD/downloads/escpos.pdf)

Trecho código (Exemplo completo no link acima):

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Const eClear As String = Chr(27) + "@"
    Public Const eCentre As String = Chr(27) + Chr(97) + "1"
    Public Const eLeft As String = Chr(27) + Chr(97) + "0"
    Public Const eRight As String = Chr(27) + Chr(97) + "2"
    Public Const eDrawer As String = eClear + Chr(27) + "p" + Chr(0) + ".}"
    Public Const eCut As String = Chr(27) + "i" + vbCrLf
    Public Const eSmlText As String = Chr(27) + "!" + Chr(1)
    Public Const eNmlText As String = Chr(27) + "!" + Chr(0)
    Public Const eInit As String = eNmlText + Chr(13) + Chr(27) + _
    "c6" + Chr(1) + Chr(27) + "R3" + vbCrLf
    Public Const eBigCharOn As String = Chr(27) + "!" + Chr(56)
    Public Const eBigCharOff As String = Chr(27) + "!" + Chr(0)

    Private prn As New RawPrinterHelper

    Private PrinterName As String = "EPSON TM-T20 Receipt"

    Public Sub StartPrint()
        prn.OpenPrint(PrinterName)
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintHeader()
        Print(eInit + eCentre + "My Shop")
        Print("Tel:0123 456 7890")
        Print("Web: www.????.com")
        Print("sales@????.com")
        Print("VAT Reg No:123 4567 89" + eLeft)
        PrintDashes()
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintBody()
        Print(eSmlText + "Tea                                          T1   1.30")

        PrintDashes()

        Print(eSmlText + "                                         Total:   1.30")

        Print("                                     Paid Card:   1.30")
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintFooter()
        Print(eCentre + "Thank You For Your Support!" + eLeft)
        Print(vbLf + vbLf + vbLf + vbLf + vbLf + eCut + eDrawer)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Print(Line As String)
        prn.SendStringToPrinter(PrinterName, Line + vbLf)
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintDashes()
        Print(eLeft + eNmlText + "-".PadRight(42, "-"))
    End Sub

    Public Sub EndPrint()
        prn.ClosePrint()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bnExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
            Handles bnExit.Click
        prn.ClosePrint()

        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bnPrint_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
            Handles bnPrint.Click
        StartPrint()

        If prn.PrinterIsOpen = True Then
            PrintHeader()

            PrintBody()

            PrintFooter()

            EndPrint()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Fonte: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704989/Print-Direct-To-Windows-Printer-EPOS-Receipt

Comment: Apesar de em vb, otimo exemplo, mas o problema é que nesse sistema há dois modos, um apenas texto e outro onde preciso fazer uso de alguns elementos graficos, por isso uso a função printdocument, que é onde estou tendo problemas. Ainda assim, obrigado.

Comment: Não deixou isto claro na pergunta, porém, este método da resposta também trabalha com elementos gráficos, imagens, código barra, etc. Poste imagem e código do modelo que está tendo problemas.